# How can I fetch user`s info when apple authentication in React native?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, apple-sign-in

talents.
How are you?
I am developing a React native app and it is needed to add apple authentication.
I am using Expo(sdk v35) and used [expo-apple-authentication](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/apple-authentication/)
library. So now I can see AppleAuthenticationCredentialState is AUTHORIZED.
The problem is how to fetch user info after that.

So I coded for fetching user info.

`let urlBody = code=${authorizationCode}&client_id=${clientId}&grant_type=authorization_code`;

```
const res = await fetch(`https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token`, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: urlBody,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
});`
```

but the result was

> Object {
>     "error": "invalid_client",
>   }

I am new to apple authentication and if anyone already implemented this feature using React native, please help me.
Best regards!!!